# Работа со свернутым окном

Tags: python, бот

Возможно ли как то сделать чтобы скрипт на питоне работал со свернутым окном?
Пишу бота для игры, хочу сделать чтобы скрипт работал со свернутой игрой и передавал туда простые команды по типу нажать кнопку.

Comment: зависит от вашей игры, никто кроме нее не ограничивает работу в фоне :)

Comment: Я хочу попробовать сделать своего бота для гта 5 рп и видел уже ботов которые работают в фоне, вот хотелось бы тоже добавить такую фичу. Как можно привязать бота к окну?

Comment: Или вообще таких ботов лучше не на python писать? Тогда на каком языке?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/wintouch/sendmessage--postmessage--and-related-functions

Comment: `pythonw.exe  you_script.py` - выполнение скрипта без окна. Если хотите иметь окно,  но свернутое - создайте ярлык для запуска скрипта. (В свойствах ярлыка можно настроить способ открытия окна.)

Comment: Не, мне надо не сам скрипт скрыть, а вот допустим у меня гта 5 свернуто и я бы хотел чтобы скрипт подсасывался в тому окну.